# Bulk import in local server for Spring Cloud Date Flow not working

Tags: spring, server, cloud, local

The bulk import feature in Spring Cloud Data Flow local server for Rabbit given in the documentation: The bit.ly url  /Bacon-RELEASE-stream-applications-rabbit-maven

is not working. I get an error in the UI that Error reading from URL. But when I try the link in my browser there is no error.

I can save the downloaded file but then how do I import it. Or why is the link not working. I go through a proxy server. Is there some special setting in the local server I need to configure?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a little unclear what you're asking here. Are you having problems executing a bulk import in code? Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some examples on how to make this question more answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk import feature should work, I have tried url bitly Bacon-RELEASE-stream-applications-rabbit-maven to bulk import and it works for me on spring cloud dataflow 1.2.3-RELEASE. By the way which version of spring cloud dataflow you are using.

Optionally you can also bulk import the applications using spring dataflow shell.

Download and Start spring cloud datflow shell

***java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar***

and bulk import rabbit maven stream applications using below command at the dataflow shell prompt

dataflow:>app import --uri bit.ly/Bacon-RELEASE-stream-applications-rabbit-maven